# Executing an Oracle stored procedure returning a REF CURSOR using SqlAlchemy

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, sqlalchemy

I have a stored procedure that I have defined in Oracle. In that procedure I need to return a recordset. To do this, I am using the `SYS_REFCURSOR`, which works great inside of Oracle (and with `cx_Oracle`, for that matter). In my application I am using SqlAlchemy scoped sessions, to support multi-threading.

How can I use the scoped session to return the `REF CURSOR`? The only way I have been able to get this to work is by declaring an out cursor with the cursor that is active in the session and then executing the stored procedure, like below:

```
sql = """
    BEGIN
        example('%s', '%s', '%s', :cur);
    END;
""" % (cid, show, type)

conn = sa_tool.session.connection()
in_cur = conn._Connection__connection.cursor()
out_cur = conn._Connection__connection.cursor()
in_cur.execute(sql, cur=out_cur)
results = out_cur.fetchall()
```

Ideally, I would like to avoid using the connection object in this way, and execute the procedure while letting SqlAlchemy manage the cursors. If that is not possible, is there a reason that the fetch would take so long?

Thanks

Comment: Well the slowness is certainly my own fault, and a bad query in the stored procedure. The question still remains, is there a better way to call a stored procedure in SqlAlchemy, using an Oracle `REF CURSOR`?

Answer (score 0):

I saw this question which was not answered and I decided to jump in. First of all, let me just say that for your scenario there is no better option than SYS_REFCURSOR. Of course, you have alternatives.

An Oracle Cursor is a memory area location where an instruction to execute a SQL statement is stored. A Ref cursor is just a pointer to the cursor location. SYS_REFCURSOR is an specific oracle defined typed of ref cursor. So when you return a SYS_REFCURSOR variable to a client, you are returning a pointer towards the memory location where the instruction to execute the SQL resides. Your client can now execute the instruction using the FETCH operation and get the rows. So this is the best possible way to return a result set to the client.

As an alternative, you might use a PIPELINED FUNCTION, but I can assure you that you won't get any better performance. AskTom has a great explanation about this comparison in this article

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9532870400346178516

Another scenario is whether you want to analyse where the time is consumed, either in the EXECUTE phase or in the FETCH one. If you have a huge time in FETCH, perhaps you might consider transfer the data in another way to the client. If you have a problem in EXECUTION, then you need to make a tuning exercise over your procedure.

Comment: Although this is a good description from the db side, I don't think it's really helpful from the SQLAlchemy side, which is what the asker seems to have needed help with.