# Execute a PL/SQL function (or procedure) from SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, oracle, plsql, sqlalchemy

I have a legacy PL/SQL function:

```
getlogin(p_username in varchar2, p_password in varchar2) return boolean;
```

How can I execute this from SQLAlchemy and get the return value?

A naive approach like this doesn't seem to work:

```
result = DBSession.execute('getlogin(:username, :password)',
                           {'username':request.POST['username'],'password':request.POST['password']});
# extract return value from result
```

From the logs I see this error:

> File "../env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0-py3.3.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 871, in _execute_context
>       context)
>     File "../env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0-py3.3.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 322, in do_execute
>       cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
>   cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

I can see it looks like the SQL interpreter is being invoked and not the PL/SQL interpreter, but I'm not sure on the next steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably have to provide a PL/SQL block to your execute call:

```
result = DBSession.execute('begin getlogin(:username, :password); end;',
                             {'username':request.POST['username'],'password':request.POST['password']});
```

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390212/executing-an-oracle-stored-procedure-returning-a-ref-cursor-using-sqlalchemy?rq=1) on SQLAlchemy + Oracle SP might also help.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `.execute()` on a connection method then you need a valid SQL statement. If `getlogin` is a function, this requires a SELECT:

```
result = DBSession.execute('select getlogin(:username, :password) from dual'
                          , {'username' : request.POST['username']
                             ,'password' : request.POST['password']});
```

As the error states, your SQL statement is invalid.

Comment: That won't work, since the function returns a Boolean (which is a PL/SQL type, not a SQL type).

Comment: Thanks for the response. The signature for getlogin() returns boolean which is valid plsql, not valid sql. Yes, I can wrap this function to return a valid SQL type. But even so, the example you provide of execute() is really a SQL call. My original question still stands though: is it possible to execute PLSQL via SQLAlchemy?

Comment: So this seems to work but how then do i view the printed `dbms_output`' statements in the pl/sql proc?